# How can I handle alerts that occur on page navigation with WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The scenario here is that certain pages I'm testing will have an unload event - i.e. prompt to save changes if there are unsaved changes is a common example and I want to be able to detect that and handle it.

**Here is the specific problem:**

I'm testing a pretty complicated web app which will allow users to edit rich content in a browser and the app will auto-save changes from the user.  So this test does something like the following:

1. Navigate to the app
2. Do some edits
3. Navigate away

However, since the app auto-saves changes on navigating away and there are unsaved changes - this prompt will show up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9iP2.png

Whenever there is an alert in Selenium, the next action will fail miserably with a callstack like:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open
  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.65)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.11.298604 (75ea2fdb5c87f133a8e1b8da16f6091fb7d5321e),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 87 milliseconds: null
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
System info: host: 'ip-10-231-174-40', ip: '10.231.174.40', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.11.0-19-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: 889cbda1d1a946a38e90e4ec9f32e827
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, hasMetadata=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir1584_15883}, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=889cbda1d1a946a38e90e4ec9f32e827, version=39.0.2171.65, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:614)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getCurrentUrl(RemoteWebDriver.java:319)
```

So one solution might be that I put try/catches whenever my test navigates away from this page but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant and systematic solution (i.e. something that would either detect alerts or page navigation so they get handled).

Does anyone have a working solution for this problem?

Comment: Updated the question with a more specific example and error callstack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to **switch to alert and accept it**. Example in Java:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

You may also need *to wait for it to appear* before switching:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

---

Alternatively, you can stop the popup to be shown in the first place. The idea is to remove all `beforeunload` event listeners with `javascript`:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript(
  "window.addEventListener(\"load\", foo, false);" +
  "function foo() { " + 
    "var u = \"beforeunload\";" + 
    "var v = unsafeWindow;" + 
    "if (v._eventTypes && v._eventTypes[u]) {" + 
      "var r=v._eventTypes[u];" + 
      "for(var s=0;s<r.length;s++) { " +
        "v.removeEventListener(u,r[s],false);" + 
      "}" +
      "v._eventTypes[u]=[];" + 
    "}");
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I'm doing now to work around the issue but I still wonder if there's a way to listen for if an alert or page navigate happens rather than poll.  I guess the answer is - not really with WebDriver Java.

Comment: @dming well, since it is chrome, you can also try controlling it's behavior with arguments. I haven't found a specific one related to this prompt, but there should be a way to disable this kind of popup. E.g. there is [disable-prompt-on-repost](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-prompt-on-repost), I'm pretty sure it won't work for this kind of prompt, but try..

Comment: @dming please also see the update. I haven't tested the approach, but give it a try.