# Handling OS based alert

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am preparing automated test script for our website.  I have a functionality for sending mail.  While sending mail outlook produces an alert to accept it to proceed sending mail.  But I could not close the alert using selenium and If I manually accept the alert the Selenium script is stopped and the test case fails.

I tried below common code in my script and it didn't work.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo
```

I know selenium web driver can't handle none web application, but is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Popup Dialogs

Starting with Selenium 2.0 beta 1, there is built in support for handling popup dialog boxes. After you’ve triggered an action that opens a popup, you can access the alert with the following:

```
       Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

source :- http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019637/how-can-i-handle-alerts-that-occur-on-page-navigation-with-webdriver?rq=1) link will help you, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019637/how-can-i-handle-alerts-that-occur-on-page-navigation-with-webdriver?rq=1) one also.

Comment: Hi Buddhika, 

I have tried the above code but it is working only for browser based alert not the OS based alerts.  

For example  we have email functionlity in our application while clicking the EMail button.  This button cause outlook to send the mail and it pops up the confirmation box for sending mail and I could not handle the alert since it is produced by the Outlook not the browser.

Thanks & Regards, 
Ganesh. K

Comment: selenium web driver only support for the web applications, that mean application need to be opened by a browser, but there can be a indirect solution for this. can i know what is the error message you are getting and if you can put the some code part of your script

Comment: Hi Buddhika,  Thanks for your time,  I am not getting any error message. I have a print functionality in the application. I have to test the functionality. While clicking the print it will call outlook and it will produce a confirmation message box to accept. When the message box pops up the selenium doesn't execute the next line.  Is there any way to handle these type of message box.  Thanks & Regards,  Ganesh. K

Comment: Put a 5 sec wait code after the open code. During 5 sec time, try to click the alert manually. Did you use a try catch or something to catch exception. What is ur language.  Java??. There should be a reason to program not going to execute the next line. Maybe that happen when a exception throw or waiting for the response come. Give me some information what I asked.